# Python: I'm having trouble taking a text file and displaying which line number a word is found

Tags: python, list, file, text, location

So I have a text file, it's a poem so there are lines, and I want it to be set up where the user enters a word and the program prints which lines the word is found. Here's what I have. I don't understand why it's not working.

```
f=open(file,'r') 
word = input('enter word: ')
data = f.read()
x= data.split('\n')
count = 0 
while word in x[count]:
    print(word,'is on line'count)
    count += 1
```

I feel like something should happen, but it doesn't. Any advice?

Alsoooo, I would also like to display which (first) character on the line the word is found? I have a general idea, but I couldn't figure out how to display it relative to the line. It displayed relative to the entire text. So it would display 'character 200' rather than 'character 5' because for the line it's on, it starts at the 5th character.

Basically I had this:
     data = f.read() /
     print(data.index(word))

Any advice would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

The loop `while word in x[count]` terminates on the first line where the word isn't on the line.

Try something like this:

```
word = input('enter word: ')
with open(file) as f: data = f.read()
lines = data.split('\n')
count = 0
for linenr, line in enumerate(lines):
    print(word, "is on line", linenr)
    if word in line:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

However, this still has a bug. If you're searching for `apple`, it will also match `applesauce`. Try fixing that as an exercise :)

Comment: this says the word is on every line in the poem which isn't the case

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initially stated issue,

> ...the program prints which lines the word is found

You want to do the following

- Get user input (the word and the poem's file)
- Open the file containing the poem
- Read the content into an *enumerated* list of the poem's lines
- For each line, if it has the user's word, print the line number and
  the line

---

**Script**

```
from sys import argv

word = argv[1]
poem = argv[2]

with open(poem) as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if word in line:
            print i, line
```

---

**Sample File**

```
God and the Soldier, we adore,
In time of danger, not before.
The danger passed and all things righted, 
God is forgotten and the Soldier slighted.
```

---

**Run**

```
> python poemscript.py danger poem.txt
1 In time of danger, not before.
2 The danger passed and all things righted,
```

Comment: I'd suggest skipping reading the file into a list (the line after the `with` line) and change the `for` line to: `for i, line in enumerate(file, start=1):`. The `start=1` argument to `enumerate` will have the line numbering start at 1 rather than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer similar to your code:

```
word = input('enter word: ')

with open(filename) as fobj:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(fobj, start=1):
        if word in line:
            print('"{word}" is on line {line_no} at column {char_pos}'.format(
                  word=word, line_no=line_no, char_pos=line.index(word)))
```